# R-parity and free neutron decay

Tags: supersymmetry, neutrons, parity

Why isn't free neutron decay:

$$ n\to p^+ + e^- + \bar{\nu_e} $$

an $R$-parity violating interaction? If all SM particles have $R=+1$, doesn't the above equation have $\sum_{LHS} R=1$ and $\sum_{RHS} R=3$? Does $R$-parity not apply when no SUSY particles are involved?

Comment: Why the downvote? Please explain.

Comment: How could that formula apply e.g. in the case when a squark decays into a quark and a chargino? $-1\neq 1-1$. But this decay does not violate R-parity.

Comment: Isn't a better idea to just use product of $R$ numbers instead of sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by [AccidentalFourierTransform](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/84967/accidentalfouriertransform), to determine whether or not a decay or interaction is $R$-parity violating, the $R$-numbers on either side of the interaction should be summed and taken $(\textrm{mod}~2)$. This means that the above decay is not $R$-parity violating.